# why is "export PATH" displayed in terminal as a title?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, xilinx

I have a long time using Ubuntu, probably 3 or 4 years, I've never had the need to "export a path".

Now, I was installing Xilinx ISE 14.7 in Kubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS following a tutorial, at some point the tutorial advised to create a PATH (I don't even know what it is, but I guess that is like a link or shorcut to launch the program easily).

The tutorial advise to run `echo "PATH=\$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/" >> ~/.bashrc echo "export PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`, now everytime I open a terminal it displays:

[image: Terminal]

### Triple Question here:

- How can I erase that undesired title there?
- Is the path a shortcut to
  execute a program?
- If so, how can I successfully do it in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely what happened is you concatenated two separate `echo` commands on a single line, causing the second *command* (complete with the `echo`) to get written to the file (instead of the *output* of the command).

- Open your `~/.bashrc` file in any text editor, and replace the line `echo export PATH` by plain `export PATH`
- It's a list of directories that are searched (in order) for the command, rather than a direct shortcut to it
- Put the commands on separate lines next time, like

  ```
  echo "PATH=\$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

  then

  ```
  echo "export PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

Comment: More for the answer I appreciate the explanation. Works like a charm.

Comment: Hey again, I have a situation here, I have the path successfully, (I think), but I am unable to run the program as root, if I type in `ise` it runs properly, but if I do `sudo ise` it doesn't work. I've tried `sudo ./ise` aswell. I've tried going root (`sudo su`) and then running just `ise` it doesn't work either.